# After updating to MacTeX 2013, font size and kerning of Monotype Corsiva are strange

Tags: fontspec, mactex, kerning

I knew I probably shouldn't have upgraded, being not very experienced, I always have to wade through strange errors. However, this is really weird.

Here's my example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex 
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 

\documentclass[20pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
Test {\fontspec{Monotype Corsiva}Test}
\end{document}
```

Yesterday, this would have rendered the two "Test" in the same size, kerning in Monotype Corsive being, well, normal. Today, after upgrading to MacTeX 2013 (but not really fiddling with the fonts) Monotype Corsiva is much smaller and has big spaces between letters.

I presume I made a mistake somewhere - but what am I doing wrong?

I am using Monotype Corsive in texts to render a corporate identity title, consisting of one word. So I can work around the issue by increasing font size and defining kerning for that one word - however, fiddling with font size increases line height and that doesn't look good either.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Can you show an image (or even the PDF) from your document, and what is the version you upgraded from?

Comment: @KhaledHosny - Thank you for answering. I uploaded two PDFs:

http://www.mycroft.ch/monotypecorsiva-before.pdf
This shows how it always was (rendered on a backup Mac with the old MacTeX (2010?) running). It's the same source as the other file below and which is in the file. 
You see how the word renders normally on page 1 and how distorted it is on page 2 with the \kern stuff.

http://www.mycroft.ch/monotypecorsiva-after.pdf
This is how it looks since I updated. What was "normal" looks weird and the artificial normal size has a weird line height.

Really thankful for ideas...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue on Linux, what is the version of the font?

Comment: It's a file name MTCORSVA.TTF, 157'360 bytes, last changed in 1998, Version 2.35

I just realized there is a second (deactivated) Monotype Corsiva, 73'706 bytes, version 2.35 of March 2011. But when I delete the other version I get a "font not found" error.

I always used the MTCORSVA.TTF, for 3 years now, without a problem.

Comment: Changing the first line to
    
    `%!TEX TS-program = xelatex`
    
and running XeLaTeX seems to help. But I'll have to see whether other files other than my test file compile well, too.
Of course, any hint is till appreciated.

Comment: OK, it seems to run well with XeLaTex, am I wrong in concluding that then it must be a LuaLaTeX problem?

Comment: I think so. Better report it to luaotfload developers, I think they are not respecting font deactivation.